# Is there any way to modify the output voltage of a laptop adapter from 18.5V to say 7V or 13.6V?

Tags: dc, switch-mode-power-supply, adapter, atx

I have an old 18.6V 6.5A adapter from an old HP docking station. I tried to open the adapter and saw an small pot inside it, tried turning it but the out just remained constant and there was no change. How can I change the output with minimal components. I had previously tried with an LM2596 Buck converter to step down the voltage unfortunately I accidentally shorted the leads and it blew up though it did work for a while, also since the input was capable of upto 6.5A if the current draw exceeded @A it could heat up pretty quic. So, my first option would be to get a similar buck conv with a 75W or 100W capability(around 5A) or I need to get the above mentioned fixed voltage or  a variable one by adding say a pot? Also is it safe? I've seen people mentioning its dangerous trying to modify ATX PSUs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is 230V AC adapter then it works with 400V DC internally, so yes, it is dangerous to mess with it for somebody who doesn't have experience. It can blow in your hands (trust me, I have experienced several such explosions, luckily with happy end).
It is much more safe to build buck regulator, that you are mentioning.

It could be even impossible to modify that adapter, even if you decided to. It depends on the construction, some are build specifically for some voltage, with specific parts.

Comment: Thanks. So, I'll give up the idea of modifying it internally. I love my hands :D. WHich is the best buck converer for getting the max current from this laptop adapter (6.5A max). Do you think XL4005 or 4015 will be a better choice? most of the high wattage (300W) ones are usually boost converter I saw on ebay or amazon. Do you know any good buck converters with higher power capability?

Comment: @RahulSalin shopping questions are off-topic. Just look for parameters, read datasheets. That is the way to find best part for you. Maybe use shops like digikey, mouser, element14, etc. to use their parametric search.